# Check Null attributes on requestBody

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have an object with `adress` as an optional attribute:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private String adress;
}
```

And a spring `RestController` with :

```
@RequestBody Person person.
```

I wanna know if the client send me a json with an `adress` with null value,
Or if he didn't send me the `adress` in the json.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

StringUtils.isBlank(request.getPerson().getAddress());

Answer (score 0):

By Default, @RequestBody is "required". If the request does not have a body provided, it will return a 400 Bad Request.

To check if address is not present in the request body, you can write a request validator before processing the data.

```
public Boolean validateRequest(Person person) {
    return !person.getAddress().isEmpty()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javax Validation,

In the Person class, use @NotNull annotation

Ex:

public class Person {

```
private String name;

@NotNull(message = "Please enter address")
private String adress;
```

}

In the Rest Controller, add @Valid annotation next to @RequestBody,

Ex :  @RequestBody @Valid Person person.

So that the value will be validated automatically.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

@NotBlank(message = " your message  xxxxxxx")
 private String adress